# Prompting user to enter details for table creation

Tags: java, jdbc

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DynamicTableCreate {

    static String url, user, password;
    static {
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/testing";
        user="root";
        password="root";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Connection con=null;
        Statement stmt=null;

        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter table name");
        String tname=scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter number of columns");
        int cols=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter column names and data types ");
        String [] colnames=new String[5];
        String [] datatype=new String[5];
        int i=0;
        while(i<cols)
        {
            colnames[i]=scan.next();
            datatype[i]=scan.next();
            i++;
        }

        // Create table Trainers (T_Id int primary key, Trainer_name varchar(20), Stream varchar(20));
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
            stmt=con.createStatement();

            String sql1 = "create table " + tname + "(" + colnames[0] + " " + datatype[0] + " primary key, ";
            for(i=1;i<cols;i++)
            {
                sql1 += colnames[i] + " " + datatype[i] + ", ";
            }
            sql1+=");";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);
        }

        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (stmt!=null)
                    stmt.close();
                if(con!=null)
                    con.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create table where user gives table name, number of columns,column names and their data types but my code throws following error :

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

What is the solution?

Comment: Did you do any research or debugging to see what the result of your SQL query was (eg. print the string out to the console or some other log)? I know the error messages MySQL returns aren't fantastic but it is explaining the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved...

The only change to be done is just replace

```
sql1 += colnames[i] + " " + datatype[i] + ", ";
```

by

```
sql1 += ", " + colnames[i] + " " + datatype[i];
```